# React Native: clicks on child components inside a ScrollView component trigger onPress event of the last item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Get an array and for each of the array elements, put them into a child component under a ScrollView.
2. When that child element is clicked, return the value of that child component.

Here is the issue: whenever I click on one of the child elements, it will return the content of the last child element. The props are passed to each of the child element without any problem--I don't know what went wrong.

Could someone advise me on what is the issue and how I can fix it? Below is the simplified code:

```
    const data = [ 0,1,2,3,4 ]

    //When clicked, the result will always show 4, regardless of which button was clicked

    const ResultLine = (props) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={{height:40}} onPress={()=>{console.log(props.data)}}>
                <Text>{props.data}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ) 
    }

    const ResultList = () => {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={{width:'100%',height:'100%'}}>
                {data.map((dt,index)=>
                    <ResultLine data={dt} key={index}/>
                )}
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am able to get the data of clicked child with your code snippet like 1, 2, 3, etc. Please recheck if this works for you too.

Comment: I recommend to use FlatList